# How to find the continuum and delete it?

Tags: python, data-modeling

I'm setting up a code that code go through spectra data and find the continuum and delete this so that the normal flux is 0 and I can correctly calculate the flux of the emission lines.

The problem is that this continuum is not really a constant, and most of the time looks like a root function (not always). How can I make it find the continuum?

This is my spectra data and this is how I find the peaks

spectra data:

```
m1 = modeling.models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=10, mean=3726, stddev=8)
m2 = modeling.models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=10, mean=3126, stddev=8)

x = np.linspace(3000, 4500, 1000)

continuum_sqrt = np.sqrt(x)*0.2

mock_spectrum = continuum_sqrt + m1(x) + m2(x)
mock_spectrum = mock_spectrum + np.sqrt(mock_spectrum) * np.random.random(x.size) - 0.5
mock_spectrum -= mock_spectrum.min()
```

And this is the guassian finding:

```
def gaussfcn(x, *p):
    """ gauss function to be used for fits to the data"""
    A, mu, sigma = p
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

class Gauss:
    """A class to hold coefficients for Gaussian distributions"""
    def __init__(self, A, mu, sigma):
        self.A = A
        self.mu = mu
        self.sigma = sigma
    def value(self, x):
        return gaussfcn(x, self.A, self.mu, self.sigma)
    def as_string(self, ndigits=4):
        return str("A: {}, mu: {}, sigma: {}".format(round(self.A, ndigits),
                                                     round(self.mu, ndigits),
                                                     round(self.sigma, ndigits)))

## set up a new plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots()  # makes new plot
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('test')

## plot the data
plt.plot(x, mock_spectrum, linestyle='steps')

## Initial guess A, mu, sigma
P0 = [12,3127,1]

coeff, var_matrix = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(gaussfcn,
                                             x,
                                             mock_spectrum,
                                             P0)

## create a Gauss object with the fitted coefficients for better code readability
g = Gauss(*coeff)
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(var_matrix))

print("Fit result: {}".format(g.as_string()))
print("Fit uncertainties [%]: {}".format(100*perr/coeff))

## plot the result
axes.plot(x, g.value(x),
          label = r'Gaussian fit, $\mu={}$, $\sigma={}$'.format(round(g.mu),round(g.sigma)))

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is more data analysis rather than programming, may be off topic here. Maybe https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is the right place.

Comment: On your request, I placed it also on data science, but there it was deleted due to it not being about data science. So if you could help me, that would be amazing

Comment: Sorry, I am not very expert in spectral fitting with lines. But in theory, rather than removing the continuum, you should fit the continuum and the line all togheter. The model should be something like: normalization constant + continuum + one gaussian for each emission line. The continuum component can be a slope, a square root or whatever seems appropriate. Once the fit is good, you can estimate the flux of each line integrating the respective gaussian.